# Ruby on Rails: create an instance that "belongs_to" another Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Well, i'm new on rails, and I has the following:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
   ...
end
```

and

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
   ...
end
```

I want to create a post, and select its category from a drop down with:

```
...
select("post", "category", Post::CATEGORIES, {:include_blank => true})
...
```

When I try to save, it says that category attribute doesnt exists.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post table contains only category id, so you need to assign to `category_id`:

```
select("post", "category_id", Post::CATEGORIES, :include_blank => true)
```

Comment: Thanks, so i have to put: <%= collection_select(:post, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>, but, how You said, its category_id instead category.

Comment: Yep, I just copy pasted what you posted originally because I wasn't sure what's inside the categories constant.